# How to edit the CSS of a td element through the hierarchy?

Tags: html, css

For example, I'd like to edit this:

```
table.organization_detail tr td {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

But the above code simply isn't doing anything, I'm not sure how to target the TD element through the above hierarchy. Essentially, there's a table with an organization_detail class that has a tr and td element. The font size on the td element is too large and I'd like to make it 20px.

What is the proper syntax to target this element?

Thanks!

edit (below is the html):

```
 <div class="organization-detail-info">
    <div class="inner-bgdown">
      <h3 class="account_titles">Account Details (<a href='#' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#account_details">Edit</a>)</h3>
      <table class="table organization_detail">
        <tr>
          <td>Name of Organization:</td>
          <td><%= @account.organization.name if @account.organization.present? %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Organization Type:</td>
          <td><%= Organization::ORG_TYPE[@account.organization.organization_type] if @account.organization.present? %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Address:</td>
          <td><%= @account.organization.address_1 if @account.organization.present? %> <%= @account.organization.address_2 if @account.organization.present? %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>City:</td>
          <td><%= @account.organization.city if @account.organization.present? %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>State/Province:</td>
          <td><%= @account.organization.state if @account.organization.present? %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zip/Postal Code:</td>
          <td><%= @account.organization.zip if @account.organization.present? %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Country:</td>
          <td><%= @account.organization.country_id if @account.organization.present? %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Phone Number:</td>
          <td><%= @account.organization.phone_number if @account.organization.present? %></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End-organization-detail-info -->
```

and CSS:

```
.organization_detail td:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 40%;
  color:#000;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height:36px;
}
.organization_detail td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 60%;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color:#000;
  font-size:20px;
}
table.organization_detail tr td {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Comment: Post your HTML and other CSS. There is likely a more specific selector that is overriding the CSS that you have posted.

Comment: Press F12, inspect a `td` in `.organization_detail`, and identify which rule (and which stylesheet) is winning.

Comment: Updated with the HTML and CSS

Comment: Thanks got it!, I was able to edit directly the .organization_detail td:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 20px;

Comment: There must be additional CSS if the td element is larger than 20px, since nothing in what you have posted would be causing that.

Comment: Dude your code is working. The problem is that the hierarchy is working exactly like it is supposed to. `.organization_detail td:nth-child(1)` is more specific than `table.organization_detail tr td`. If you want it to override you have to be more specific. `table.organization_detail tr td` is saying the same thing as `.organization_detail td`. Almost exactly same level of detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment above so to clarify why both snippets are completely posted here.

"Dude your code is working. The problem is that the hierarchy is working exactly like it is supposed to. `.organization_detail td:nth-child(1)` is more specific than `table.organization_detail tr td`. If you want it to override you have to be more specific. `table.organization_detail tr td` is saying the same thing as `.organization_detail td`. Almost exactly same level of detail."

This is your code...

```css
.organization_detail td:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 40%;
  color:#000;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height:36px;
}
.organization_detail td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 60%;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color:#000;
  font-size:20px;
}
table.organization_detail tr td {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="organization-detail-info">
    <div class="inner-bgdown">
      <h3 class="account_titles">Account Details (<a href='#' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#account_details">Edit</a>)</h3>
      <table class="table organization_detail">
        <tr>
          <td>Name of Organization:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Organization Type:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Address:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>City:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>State/Province:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zip/Postal Code:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Country:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Phone Number:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the code I think you're trying to get to.

```css
.organization_detail td:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 40%;
  color:#000;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height:36px;
}
.organization_detail td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 60%;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color:#000;
}
.inner-bgdown table.organization_detail tr td {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="organization-detail-info">
    <div class="inner-bgdown">
      <h3 class="account_titles">Account Details (<a href='#' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#account_details">Edit</a>)</h3>
      <table class="table organization_detail">
        <tr>
          <td>Name of Organization:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Organization Type:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Address:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>City:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>State/Province:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zip/Postal Code:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Country:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Phone Number:</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as regular CSS this would look something like this

```
TD.class#id{}
```

or

```
TD#id{}
```

you can also do

```
TD.class{}
```

or even just

```
TD{}
```

each one of these work with basic CSS

In most cases you want to do the (Tag.class#id) mainly if you have allot of data
where other cases with less data (tag#id) would also work.

now if you want to Simplify it just use the class or id only

```
.class{}
#id{}
```

EDIT basically element targets dont contain spaces and you can cut the length some by adding an ID to the desired element

```
<td id="ex" class="example"...>...</td>
```

Comment: ? I don't fully understand how you are answering the question.. You are laying out the structure of how CSS works, but not for his case. It is a little more specific in that his classes are working exactly how they are supposed to, but not understanding why.

Comment: thats all he needed was to know how to TARGET the element according to the second to last line in the question. the issue is he is does not have it targeted correctly according to regular CSS syntax. so I provided a few proper ways to try ideally all of these would work.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried simply giving that  element an ID?

i.e.

```
    #exampleTD{
        font-size: 20px;
   }

    <td id="exampleID">

    </td>
```

instead of an ID, try adding it as a class so that you can affect more than one .

```
.exampleClass{
font-size: 20px;
}
<td class="exampleClass">
</td>
```

Comment: Please don't do this. Extremely bad practice. Especially if you are selecting multiple `td` which you are.

Comment: Id should be used definitely in this case.

Comment: looking that the code he has, shouldn't it inherit the 20px font-size from the <table> element anyways?

Comment: @CoreyTimm yes it does.